# Arraybuffer is not assinable to type string, Angular. I am trying to show uploaded image on the page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've used a snipped to show the image that the user selected. The code worked but on the editor I get an error on the line shown below. I knew as soon as I stopped the development server and run it again it wouldn't compile anymore, And that happened.

```
 srcFotos: Array<string>;



onFileSelect(event, index) {


      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
          const file = event.target.files[0];
  
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = e => {
            alert(reader.result);

           this.srcFotos[index] =  reader.result; //Arraybuffer is not assinable to type string
          };
  
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
     
   

    }
```

on template

```
     <img [src]="srcFotos[1]" class="img-fluid">
```

Like I said the code was working like expected, I selected the image and it appeared on the page despite of the error.

Comment: I think reader.result.toString() was enough.

Comment: [aside] Don't use a FileReader here, just do `const file = event.target.files[0]; this.srcFotos[index] = URL.createObjectURL( file )` is async, so easier to manage, creates only a pointer to the actual file on disk so uses **way** less memory than reading it entirely to a base64 string, and your compiler will probably love it better too, since it can only return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce the compiler to see it as a string with as

`this.srcFotos[index] =  reader.result as string;`